# How to sort value by Python by directory file read

Tags: python, file

Problem.txt file:

```
Class    Confidence     Xmin       Ymin     Xmax      Ymax
6        0.9917297      62         0        81        76
1        0.99119675     0          41       8         83
9        0.8642462      23         31       46        98
4        0.8287333      22         30       45        95
```

My expected output is:

```
1        0.99119675     0          41       8         83
4        0.8287333      22         30       45        95
9        0.8642462      23         31       46        98
6        0.9917297      62         0        81        76
```

My code is given bellow:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'F:\GGR\process'):  # this recurses into subdirectories as well
    for f in files:
        maxima = defaultdict(int)
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(root,f)) as ifh:
                for line in ifh:
                    key, value = line.rsplit(None, 1)
                    value = int(value)
                    if value > maxima[key]:
                        maxima[key] = value

            with open(os.path.join(root, f'{f}.out'), 'w') as ofh:
                for key in sorted(maxima):
                    ofh.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, maxima[key]))
        except ValueError:
            # if you have other files in your dir, you might get this error because they
            # do not conform to the structure of your "needed" files - skip those
            print(f, "Error converting value to int:", value)
```

After run this script, Output will show:

```
1 0.99119675  0  41  8   83
4 0.8287333  22  30  45  95
6 0.9917297  62  0   81   76
9 0.8642462  23  31  46  98
```

I can't understand what is the wrong in my code. Please fix this problem anf how can i get expected output for this program ?

Comment: Your error is the use of `defaultdict`, you should be using `OrderedDict`. The order of data stored in / printed from a dictionary is unpredictable due to how the hashes of the keys are calculated and stored. OrderedDict will provide dictionary-like functionality while maintaining the order in which the elements were added to it.

Comment: dictionaries in python >=3.6 keep their insertion order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: Agreed, however the OP doesn't state which version of Python 3 is being used

Comment: When used orderDict that you mentioned then error prompt will show like: NameError: name 'OrderedDict' is not defined

Comment: `OrderedDict` has to be imported from collections. However, looking more carefully at your code, I believe the error is also related to the use of `sorted`. You're likely reading your file properly, however, this line `for key in sorted(maxima)` sorts the keys being used to print. If you notice the key / value pairs, the keys are sorted. Remove `sorted`, and use `OrderedDict` (if Python3 < 3.6) and it _should_ work as intended.

Comment: Already import OrderDict  and used this in my code but i can't understand actually because i'm not familiar with Python file. Please fix this error!!

Answer (score 0):

**You're getting the output stated due to this line:**

`for key in sorted(maxima):`

This means that if your keys were `6, 1, 9, 4` they would become `1, 4, 6, 9`, which is *exactly* the order they're displayed in the output you showed. **What you want is for the dictionary to be *read and output* in the order it was added.** If you're using Python3.6 and greater, remove the `sorted` and the output will be printed in the order that the data was added.

If you're using an earlier version of Python3, you'll need a container that can keep track of the order in which the keys and values were added, *in addition to* the **removal** of `sorted`. That is make `maxima` an `OrderedDict` (this is from the `collections` package), *and* convert the for loop that prints the keys to `for key in maxima`.